# Setting parent Proptypes to children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, react-proptypes

I am rewritting jsx to tsx and I've a problem with setting the proper type to a child element. Here is an example:

```
PropTypes.shape({
  createdDate: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  modifiedDate: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  communications: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      createdDate: PropTypes.string.createdDate,
      modifiedDate: PropTypes.string.modifiedDate,
    }),
  )
});
```

Is it correct? So communication object has the same types of properties as the parent, right?

So the solution is to just make it this way?

```
type Props = {
  createdDate: string;
  modifiedDate: string;
  communications: {
    createdDate: string;
    modifiedDate: string;
    }[];
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this code is invalid since there is not such thing `PropTypes.string.createdDate`

Comment: @DennisVash Thanks, Dennis. I couldn't find such an example of usage for propTypes and I've thought that it might be correct.